# Java error when running Mapreduce program

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a MapReduce Program which aggregates the total stock volume in a stock exchange data set. I have compiled & created a jar file without any errors. But when i run the jar on Hadoop cluster it throws me a java class notfound exception. I am new to java and any help will be greatly appreciated

```
cloudera@cloudera-vm:~$ hadoop jar NYSE.jar -D com.rashmi.mapreduce.NYSE.NYSEJob /user/NYSE/NASDAQ_daily_prices_A_sample.csv /user/NYSE/outputException in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -D
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:179)
```

Comment: You have used -D option which is used for setting value for property. From the command it looks like you have used -D option incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please correct the command as:

```
hadoop jar NYSE.jar com.rashmi.mapreduce.NYSE.NYSEJob /user/NYSE/NASDAQ_daily_prices_A_sample.csv /user/NYSE/output
```

You need not use `-D` option here.

hope [this(link)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage) helps